# Fill a form through javascript (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to fill [this login form](https://www.boxtal.com/fr/fr/app/utilisateur/connexion) and submit it like that:

```js
document.querySelector('#username').value="my@email";
document.querySelector('#username').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
document.querySelector('#password').value="mypassword";
document.querySelector('#password').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
document.querySelector('button[class~="btn-red"]').click();
```

But the website displays the message that the email and password are empty. I guess its waiting for a key press or something.

How can I simulate that?

Comment: Try to emit the event `input` instead of `change`

Comment: @NullDev Thank you, that works ! Can you post as an answer ?

Comment: Posted it as answer! :)

Comment: Thank you, I validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead of the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event:

```js
document.querySelector('#username').value="my@email";
document.querySelector('#username').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
document.querySelector('#password').value="mypassword";
document.querySelector('#password').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
document.querySelector('button[class~="btn-red"]').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.boxtal.com/fr/fr/app/utilisateur/connexion', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  });

  await page.waitFor('#username');

  await page.type('#username','my@email');;

  // await browser.close();
})();
```

If you are using puppeteer you can use the code above to type in an input field

Comment: In fact I'm not using puppeteer but php headless chromium that doesn't have that method.